# Drupal 7 hide contentype permission in the admin->permission

Tags: permissions, drupal-7

In the apigee it comes with content type article,basic page, image, video, Audio, t form a long list in the permission tab(`admin->permisson`), I need to hide those content type permission (`article-create, edit,edit own, delete own, delete any`) in the tab, because its no longer going to use.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to hide those permissions?. I mean that configuration is available only for the administrator role. But the administrator could grant the permissions to any role you create,so, you shouldn't hide any configuration for the administrator.